# Issues with FindPlanarColoring

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I tried to use **FindPlanarColoring** on the following  planar graph:

```
    g=Graph[List[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],List[UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,3],UndirectedEdge[2,4],UndirectedEdge[2,5],UndirectedEdge[4,6],UndirectedEdge[4,7],UndirectedEdge[8,9],UndirectedEdge[8,10],UndirectedEdge[9,3],UndirectedEdge[9,11],UndirectedEdge[11,12],UndirectedEdge[11,10],UndirectedEdge[3,5],UndirectedEdge[5,7],UndirectedEdge[7,12],UndirectedEdge[12,13],UndirectedEdge[10,13],UndirectedEdge[13,14],UndirectedEdge[15,16],UndirectedEdge[16,17],UndirectedEdge[17,18],UndirectedEdge[18,15],UndirectedEdge[8,18],UndirectedEdge[14,17],UndirectedEdge[1,15],UndirectedEdge[6,16],UndirectedEdge[6,14]],List[Rule[GraphLayout,"TutteEmbedding"],Rule[VertexLabels,List["Name"]]]]
```

[image: original planar graph]

The following code is copied from  Application section of the document on **PlanarFaceList**:

```
faces=PlanarFaceList[g];
colors=FindPlanarColoring[g,ColorData[106,"ColorList"]];
coords=AssociationThread[VertexList[g]->GraphEmbedding[g]];
gc=Graphics[Table[Style[Polygon[faces[[i]]/.coords],colors[[i]]],{i,Length[colors]}]];
Show[gc,g]
```

The result is

[image: face colored graph]

Note that two adjacent faces {1,2,5,3} and {2,4,7,5} have the same color . Is this simply a bug or an expected behavior of **FindPlanarColoring**?

I'm using Version 13.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

We need to delete the largest polygon since the largest polygon cover the the polygons before it. In this cases, we need to remove the second polygon.

```
Clear[polys, index, pics];
polys = Table[Polygon[faces[[i]] /. coords], {i, 1, Length[colors]}];
pics = Table[
   Graphics[Style[Polygon[faces[[i]] /. coords], colors[[i]]]], {i, 
    Length[colors]}]

index = PositionLargest[Area@polys] (* v13.2 *)
index = Position[Area@polys, Max@Area@polys][[1]]

Show[Drop[pics, index], g]
```

[image]

> `{2}`

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! I now understand the origin of the issue. PlanarFaceList returns simply a valid polygonal decomposition of a sphere. I have thought that the list of faces PlanarFaceList[g] returns coincides with what we expect from the embedded image of the graph g. However, topologically speaking, there are many choices of the outer-most polygon, or equivalently, invisible side of polygonal decomposition of the sphere. What you are suggesting is a nice way to choose one such face.

Comment: NIce! But the code seems to need a slight modification. The first one is: `index = ResourceFunction["PositionLargest"][Area@polys];`The second one is: `Show[Drop[pics, {index}], g]`.

Comment: @licheng  `PositionLargest` is a built-in function since v13.2

Comment: @cvgmt  Thanks for telling me. It is OK in  v13.2,  the  index  will be the list  {2} , which is different from the value "2" obtained by the  function ResourceFunction["PositionLargest"].